# Getting the value of a checkbox

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

This is code I found when searching to understand and learn about Tkinter, but it gives an error on check box toggle.

```
from Tkinter import * 
    class Example(Frame):
    
    
        def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
            self.parent = parent
            self.initUI()
    
        def initUI(self):      
            self.parent.title("Windows")
    
    
            Label(text="Contact List").grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
            Text(width=30,height=15).grid(row=1,rowspan=9, column=0,columnspan=2,padx=20)
            Button(text="Display Contact").grid(row=10, column=0,columnspan=2,pady=10)
            Label(text="Last Name:").grid(row=11, column=0,pady=10)
            Entry().grid(row=11,column=1)
            Button(text="Search").grid(row=12,column=0,columnspan=2)
            Label(text="New Contact").grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=2)
            Label(text="First Name:").grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=E)
            Entry().grid(row=1,column=3)
            Label(text="Last Name:").grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=E)
            Entry().grid(row=2,column=3)
            Label(text="Phone #:").grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=E)
            Entry().grid(row=3,column=3)
            
            friend_check = IntVar()
            Checkbutton(variable=friend_check, command = self.friend_box, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text = "Friend").grid(row=4,column=3,sticky=W)
            
            #Label(text="Friend").grid(row=4,column=3,padx=20,sticky=W)
            Label(text="Email:").grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=E)
            Entry().grid(row=5,column=3)
            Label(text="Birthday:").grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=E)
            Entry().grid(row=6,column=3)
            Button(text="Add Contact").grid(row=7,column=3,sticky=E)
    
    
        def friend_box(self):
    
            if self.friend_check.get() == 1:
                print '1'
            else:
                print '0'
    
    
    def main():
    
        root = Tk()
        
        root.geometry("600x450+900+300")
        root.resizable(0,0)
        app = Example(root)
        root.mainloop()  
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

This is the error mentioned above:

> AttributeError: Example instance has no attribute 'friend_check'
>
> Exception in Tkinter callback

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking too many shortcuts in your code. Let's look at an example:

```
Label(text="Contact List").grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
```

This creates a `Label`, but doesn't save a reference to it. It will display in the GUI, but if you ever want to refer back to it, you'll be unable to. This is important when you have something like an `Entry` widget, to which you're pretty much guaranteed to want to use again (for the `get()`).

Another issue is that you have the geometry management chained to the widget creation. If you did save a reference to this, it would simply point to `None`, which is the value returned by geometry management methods.

To fix this, unchain the statements and save a reference:

```
self.cl_label = Label(text="Contact List")
self.cl_label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)
```

Do this for each widget you create.

For `friend_check`, you need to make it an instance variable instead of a local variable, as local variables are not usable outside their scope and get discarded when the containing function ends. Do this by prepending `self.` to the reference name.

```
self.friend_check = IntVar()
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'friend_check' is not defined with self. added. Thank you for enumerated issues

Comment: Yes, that's why I said to call it `self.friend_check`. Use that name everywhere, rather than simply `friend_check`.

Comment: Glad to hear it! You can indicate that this answer solved your issue by clicking the check mark below its score.

Comment: You also need to make sure you define `self.friend_check` _before_ you initialize the UI. The code as posted does it after.  That's the root cause of the error in the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley - in the original question, that variable was being defined at an appropriate time. However, the OP has since edited the question's code to include this answer's suggested `self.`, and moved the definition to the `__init__()`. I'll roll it back so the question makes sense again.